# Convert Data Frame to string in pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to convert Pandas Data Frame to string so that i can use in regex

Input Data:

```
SRAVAN
KUMAR
RAKESH
SOHAN
```

```
import re

import pandas as pd

file = spark.read.text("hdfs://test.txt")

pands = file.toPandas()

schema: pysark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame

result = re.sub(r"\n","",pands,0,re.MULTILINE)

print(result)
```

```
SRAVANKUMAR
RAKESHSOHAN
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? A dataframe doesn't need to be a string to use regex. Each element of the dataframe is already a string and you can loop over it using apply method to extract data with regex or any other string function

Comment: I have a file  with new lines for few records, by doing this it will be in a record fashion where ever new line exists  at end of line. Can you  tweak my code , Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Pandas for this. Spark has its own regex replace function.

This will replace `\n` in every row with an empty string.

By default, `spark.read.text` will read each line of the file into one dataframe row, so you cannot have a multi-line string value, anyway...

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace

df = spark.read.text("hdfs://test.txt")
df = df.select(regexp_replace(col('value'), '\n', ''))
df.show()
```

To get the dataframe into a joined string, collect the dataframe. But this should be avoided for large datasets.

```
s = '\n'.join(d['value'] for d in df.collect())
```